# How to align two elements on header side by side on CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS and I am trying to align the Heading and the search on the same line but I got stuck. Here is the HTML:

HTML:

```html
        <header>
                <h1 id="Heading"><a href="home.html">Welcome Home</a></h1>
                <form id="search">
                    <label for="keywordBox">Search: </label>
                    <input id="keywordBox" type="text" name="keywordsrch">
                </form>
        </header>
```

How do I align the Heading with the form? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The old way would be to float the header elements like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
  header > h1,
  header > form {
    float: left;
  }
  header {
    clear: both;
  }
</style>
```

Alternatively, the more modern and arguably better way would be to use CSS grids to do this, like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
  header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
</style>
```

The value `1fr` means "one flexible unit" and is proportional to other flexible units. Thus, in this case, it would be equivalent to 50% 50%.

Comment: I tried that but the nav below the header just covered everything

Comment: Which approach did you try? If you tried the first, you may need to set the widths explicitly for the h1 and the form.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  padding: 10px;
}

#heading,
#search {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

#search {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="heading"><a href="home.html">Welcome Home</a></h1>
  <form id="search">
    <label for="keywordBox">Search: </label>
    <input id="keywordBox" type="text" name="keywordsrch">
  </form>
</header>
```

Comment: I tried this one but the search form just hides behind the nav bar

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
         margin: 0px;
     }
    header{
        padding: 0px 15px;
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #search {
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
                <h1 id="Heading"><a href="home.html">Welcome Home</a></h1>
                <form id="search">
                    <label for="keywordBox">Search: </label>
                    <input id="keywordBox" type="text" name="keywordsrch">
                </form>
        </header>
```